# React js Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, render

i'm doing a condition for a update in my code. Basically,
my code is working with this line

```
{this.state.index === 20 ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }
```

(this line is in the render)

And now i want to do a comparaison with a variable.
but when i'm doing

```
{this.state.index === this.state.list.length ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }
```

i have the error

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I don’t understand the difference between the two lines, so I can’t understand why I have this mistake. Can someone explain to me why I have this? thx

UPDATE: my render :

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
          Search Film :
      <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
      <input
        type='text'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <input
        type='submit'
      />
      </form>
         {this.state.list.slice(this.state.index, this.state.index2).map(function(stock, id){
         return (<p key={id}> Title : {stock.title}  <br></br>release date : {stock.release_date}<br></br> popularité : {stock.popularity} <br></br> résumé : {stock.overview.substring(0,150)}...</p>)})}

         {this.state.index === this.state.list.length ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }
     {this.state.index === -1 ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }


        Top {this.state.list.length} Search : {this.state.index + 1}/ {this.state.list.length}
        <button onClick={() => {this.setState({index: this.state.index + 1,index2: this.state.index2 + 1})}}>Next Film</button>
    <button onClick={() => {this.setState({index: this.state.index - 1,index2: this.state.index2 - 1})}}>Previous Film</button>
    </div>

    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you doing `setState` inside `render` method?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma yes in a onClick (in a button)

Comment: Can you add full code of inside `render` method?

Comment: my post is updated @ShubhamVerma

Comment: {this.state.index === this.state.list.length ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }
     {this.state.index === -1 ? this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1}) : null }
issue is with these lines, 
When you call setState it re renders the component, and based on the condition setState is called continuously hence the error, you need to simplify this logic

Comment: does it happen on initial render or after you click button or type on input? and can you give example what is the value for index, index2, and list.length when it happens

Comment: @NikkoKhresna It's happening at the first rendering. And basically, index and index2 are just numbers. in a first draw, index = 0, index1 = 1 and the length = 2 (but the length can change)

Comment: You are still using `setState` inside render method. That's why its breaking. Move your logic either in `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks to Shubham and @Avinash. It was the fact i was doing my logic in the rendering ^^ i just moved this part of my code in a function executed when i was clicking in the button and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the setState in my rendering.

To fix the problem, i just changed the position of my condition.

Basically, in my rendering, i'm calling a function when i'm using the button

```
<button onClick={() => {this.checkclick()}}>Next Film</button>
```

and the function is just doing the same as before

```
checkclick() {
    this.setState({index: this.state.index + 1,index2: this.state.index2 + 1})
    if (this.state.index === this.state.list.length)
      this.setState({index: 0,index2: 1})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do not set a path in the router, I face this problem. After that I used the path name in the `PrivateRoute` of the router and it worked.

Wrong:

[image: without path name]

Right:

[image: with path name]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 